# Selecting nested div in a li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The user hovers the mouse over a menu item, i then want to show the submenu to the user. I want to use Jquery to show and hide the sub-nav-conatiner div. the only trouble is my jQuery show and hides ALL submenus - i want to display just one. So I need to select the currently hovered nested div, hope that makes sense. I have tried all sorts with no luck :(

```
     <ul> 

            <li><a href="/classifieds/farming"> 
             Agriculture & Farming</a> 
            </li> 

             <li class="sub-menu-header"><a href="#">Test Header </a> 
                  <div class="sub-nav-container"> 
                     <div class="sub-panel"> 
                         <ul> 
                            <li><a href="">Electrical Goods</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="">Electrical Goods</a></li> 
                         </ul> 
                       <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div> 
                  </div>
              </li> 

        ...
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $('.sub-nav-container').css('display', 'none !important;');
         });
         $('.sub-menu-header').mouseover(function () {
             ?????????
         });
         $('.sub-menu-header').mouseleave(function () {
             $('.sub-nav-container').css('display', 'none !important;');
         });
```

Comment: Are you aware that this can be achieved by CSS only with the pseudo `:hover` for all modern browsers? (not IE6 of course)

Comment: Yes- I have implemented this for people with javascript turned off. I wanted to improve it by adding a delay so the menu doesn't dissappear instantly when the user moves their mouse out of the sub-menu. I just need to know how to select the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `this`.

```
$('.sub-menu-header').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('div.sub-nav-container').show();
});
```

You can simplify the code, however - no need for separate `mouseover` and `mouseleave` handlers. Just use `.hover()` with a single function argument:

```
$('.sub-menu-header').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('div.sub-nav-container').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks - I knew it would be something with "this"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub-menu-header').mouseover(function () {
 $(this).children(".sub-nav-container").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub-menu-header').mouseover(function () {
    $('.sub-nav-container', this).show();
});
```