# Refer to nested div element on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Refer to nested `div` element on click event

I am having hard time to trigger the event from the click on `#mydata` link.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu example" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">
      <div id="#mydata">
        data
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
```

How do I set up `$('.example').click(function(e) {` so that once `data` gets clicked I can trigger the events.

Comment: What's wrong with just `$("#mydata").`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting nested div in a li element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113017/selecting-nested-div-in-a-li-element)

Comment: Since the actual ID starts with a `#`, you have to escape the `#` in the selector: `$("#\\#test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `on` method and use `div` as a selector

Like so:

```
$('a[role="menuitem"]').on('click', 'div', function(e){
    console.log(this);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach the click handler to the `#mydata` div?  As `#mydata` is an ID, there should only be one of them.

```
$('#mydata').click( function() { ...
```

If you want, you can delegate the click from `.example`:

```
$('.example').on('click', '#mydata', function() { ...
```

But, this won't be useful unless `#mydata` is dynamic (i.e. is added after the page loads).

If you want a click handle on each `li`, etc, do:

```
$('.example').on('li', '#mydata', function() { ...
```